# Align \itemize in description enviroment in beamer class

Tags: beamer, align, itemize, description

I have an itemized list in a description enviroment, it looks like this:
[image]

But I want, that all items are aligned under the first item with "Bob wählt...".

My code looks like this, I tried to change the template with `defbeamertemplate{description item}{align left}{\insertdescriptionitem\hfill}` and `\setbeamertemplate` but it doesn't work.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usecolortheme{default}

% PACKAGES
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}[ngerman]
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{acronym}

\defbeamertemplate{description item}{align left}{\insertdescriptionitem\hfill}

\begin{document}

\subsection{Algorithmus}
\begin{frame}{Algorithmus}
    \setbeamertemplate{description item}[align left]
    \begin{description}
    \item[Schlüsselerzeugung]
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Bob wählt eine super wachsende Folge $b = (b_1, \dots, b_n)$,
        \item einen Modul $m > \sum_{i = 1}^n b_i$,
        \item einen Multiplikator $w$ mit $\ggt(w, m) = 1$
        \item und berechnet den öffentlichen Schlüssel $a$ mit $a_i = b_i w \bmod m$
        \end{itemize}
    \item[Verschlüsselung]
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Alice verschlüsselt Nachricht $m = (m_1, \dots, m_n) \in \{0, 1\}$ zu $c = \sum_{i=1}^n m_i a_i$.
        \end{itemize}
    \item[Entschlüsselung]
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Bob entschlüsselt den Chiffretext $c$ durch $P = c w^{-1} \bmod m$.
        \end{itemize}
    \end{description}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `beamer` documentation follows:

> \begin{description}[<⟨default overlay specification⟩>][⟨long text⟩]
> ⟨environment contents⟩
> \end{description}

where `⟨long text⟩` is the longest label of description  items:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usecolortheme{default}

% PACKAGES
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}[ngerman]
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{acronym}

\defbeamertemplate{description item}{align left}{\insertdescriptionitem\hfill}

\begin{document}

\subsection{Algorithmus}
\begin{frame}{Algorithmus}
    \setbeamertemplate{description item}[align left]
    \begin{description}[Schlüsselerzeugung] % <---
    \item[Schlüsselerzeugung]
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Bob wählt eine super wachsende Folge $b = (b_1, \dots, b_n)$,
        \item einen Modul $m > \sum_{i = 1}^n b_i$,
        \item einen Multiplikator $w$ mit $ggT(w, m) = 1$
        \item und berechnet den öffentlichen Schlüssel $a$ mit $a_i = b_i w \bmod m$
        \end{itemize}
    \item[Verschlüsselung]
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Alice verschlüsselt Nachricht $m = (m_1, \dots, m_n) \in \{0, 1\}$ zu $c = \sum_{i=1}^n m_i a_i$.
        \end{itemize}
    \item[Entschlüsselung]
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Bob entschlüsselt den Chiffretext $c$ durch $P = c w^{-1} \bmod m$.
        \end{itemize}
    \end{description}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW, you not define command `\ggt`, so in MWE above I use just `ggT`. You can correct this easily.

Comment: thank you, this helps a lot!